# Reference to footnotes which outside of the current narrowed part buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

During working within a narrowed part of a buffer by issuing `C-x n s`,
reference to footnotes, it will prompt

```
Definition is outside narrowed part of buffer [2 times]
```

The a sequence of operations should be operated:
- `M-x widen` - back to the original,
- View the footnote
- Back to the focus
- `C-x n s` return to narrowed part

Is it possible to reference to footnotes outside of the narrowed part?

I tried clone-indirect-buffer as
1) C-x n s narrow
2) clone-indirect-buffer and widen
3) back to the original narrowed
This solution does not work

and solution 2

1) clone-indirect-buffer
2) C-x n s narrow the original buffer
3) reference footnote in the original buffer, 
still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try to use `clone-indirect-buffer` and keep the clone widen and the original file narrowed ?  In the clone you could jump to footnote.

Comment: ty, please review my revised question. @alinsoar tried two solution but seems not work.